# How to find the general solution of $\sin \left(x+\frac{2\pi }{3}\right)=3\sin \left(x+\frac{\pi }{3}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the ***general solution*** of the equation.

> \begin{eqnarray} \sin \left(x+\frac{2\pi }{3}\right)=3\sin \left(x+\frac{\pi }{3}\right)\\ \end{eqnarray}

The answers in my textbook are $n\pi -\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)$.

> \begin{eqnarray}
> \\\sin \left(x+\frac{2\pi }{3}\right)=3\sin \left(x+\frac{\pi }{3}\right)\\
> \\cos \left(x+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)=3\cos \left(x-\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\\
> \end{eqnarray}

What should I do?

Would you mind telling me the method for solving this question?

***Thank you for your attention.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac32\sin x+\frac{3\sqrt3}2\cos x=3\sin\left(x+\frac\pi3\right)=\sin\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)=-\frac12\sin x+\frac{\sqrt3}2\cos x\implies$$

$$3\tan x+3\sqrt3=-\tan x+\sqrt3\iff4\tan x=-2\sqrt3\iff\tan x=-\frac{\sqrt3}2\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

Try using sin(a+b)=sinacosb+cosasinb